# Laptop clock speed too high

Tags: cpu, windows-8.1, clockspeed

My Laptop clock speed is permanently higher than it should be. I have an Intel i7-3632QM clocked at 2.2GHz, but it is permamently clocking around 3GHz. I was wondering whether this why this might be, and how i might fix it as my PC gets hot even when in light use.

[Tasklist CSV output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-lFO8Hqu0sQVEppQlhXaTh6ekU/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Task manager shows my PC at 2.8 GHz but my processor clocked at 2.2Ghz]

Comment: Can you confirm you didn't overclock it? Also, do you have any overclocking software? Lastly, has this always been the case or only recently (if only recently, did you install any new programs/hardware)

Comment: What's your laptop model? What did you try so far?

Comment: I haven't knowingly overclocked it. I wouldn't know how. It has pretty much been always like this

Comment: i have a clevo we550-eu, processor as above, 8gb ram.

Comment: If it's new, you can ask the shop about it... Also, download CPU-Z just to confirm it agree's with the speeds etc (it should be the same, but it's best to check)

Comment: its not new (~6 months) and i knew it got hot, but i'd never noticed this clock speed issue and so i was wondering whether this might be the cause of the overheating in the first place. CPU-z says the same thing as taskmng.

Comment: i haven't tried much to fix it, bios has no options that i can see on this matter

Comment: It sounds like EIST (SpeedStep) is off. This CPU can raise its clock speed up to 3.2GHz if power limitations and heat allow. Check both the BIOS settings and your OS's power management settings.

Comment: i reset power management and all is now well. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU isn't overclocked. It can go up to 3.2GHz if power limitations and heat limitations allow. Make sure EIST (SpeedStep) is on in the BIOS and check your OS's power management settings.